# Out Of Bounds Expeption location (JAVA)

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand where the out of bounds exeption is happening. The compiler said its here `if(content[i] == delSub[j])` and out of bounds by 5. is that really where its happening and if so why?

```
char[] content = new char []{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'};
//SubString = BCDEF
public int deleteSubString(String delSubString) 
{
    int count = 0;
    char[] delSub = new char[delSubString.length()];
    String temp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < delSub.length;j++)
        {
                if(content[i] == delSub[j])
                {
                temp = temp + content[i];
                }
        }
    }


    return 0;
    //TODO configure return statement conditions

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs down I guess, No answer huh? Mental note don't use stack overflow on the weekends...

Comment: You haven't shown from where the `deleteSubString()` method is being called and what is being passed. Some simple debugging would definitely help you.

Comment: @user2780490: Don't be petulant. You're getting voted down because your question shows minimal effort. You refer to the "compiler" even though your program fails at runtime, you don't show the error message you were given when running, and you act as though you don't trust the stack trace you were given, which tells you exactly what and where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; i < delSub.length;j++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < delSub.length;j++)
```

(note the "j <" instead of "i <")

Comment: now I feel like a scrub :(

Comment: Ill give you the thumbs up when the timer runs down

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running out of the boundries of delSub[j] - since your condition in the inner loop checks the value of `i` instead of `j`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use j for the for condition match 
    for (int j = 0; i < delSub.length;j++)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to address *just* this part of your Question.

> ... is that really where its happening ...

Yes.  It is.  (See other answers for an explanation ...)

But more to the point, **there is no good reason** to doubt that that is where it is happening unless:

- you have stuffed up, and the source code you are looking at doesn't match the code that you are running, or
- there is a JVM bug that causes it to get the line number incorrect.  And there isn't.  Sun / Oracle JVMs give reliable line numbers in stack traces... for as long as I can remember.

In short - trust the evidence in a stacktrace.